# How do I install an old version of Django on virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, setuptools, virtualenv

I want to install some specific version of a package (in this case Django) inside the virtual environment. I can't figure it out.

I'm on Windows XP, and I created the virtual environment successfully, and I'm able to run it, but how am I supposed to install the Django version I want into it? I mean, I know to use the newly-created `easy_install` script, but how do I make it install Django 1.0.7? If I do `easy_install django`, it will install the latest version. I tried putting the version number `1.0.7` into this command in various ways, but nothing worked.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

There was never a Django 1.0.7. The 1.0 series only went up to 1.0.4. You can see all the releases in the [tags section of the Django code repository](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases).

However to answer your question, don't use `easy_install`, use `pip`. (If it's not already installed, do `easy_install pip`, then never touch easy_install again). Now you can do:

```
pip install Django==1.0.4
```

Comment: Although pip has some nice advantages over easy_install, "easy_install Django==1.0.4" would work just as well in this case.

Comment: this no longer works.  at least not for easy_install - it leads to http://www.djangoproject.com/m/bad-installer.txt (and pip seems to be broken for python2.4 which is what i am using in virtualenv).  yeah, it would be better if people used new versions, but some of us have to maintain old code...

Comment: I asked a similar question in a comment to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19180081/123033), with a response suggesting: `pip install git+github.com/django/django@1.2.5#egg=django==1.2.5`

Comment: 'the tags section' link is dead, but releases with minor version can be found here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/
oddly I didn't find this page from the django doc. replace '2.0' by '2.1' in some months..

Comment: Also - to see all available versions you can do `pip install django==` (without a version number).

Answer (score 3):

+1 on the previous poster's reply: use `pip` if you can. But, in a pinch, the easiest way is to install an older version would be to download the tarball from the [downloads](http://www.djangoproject.com/download/) page or, if you have subversion installed, do an `svn export` of the release you want (they are all tagged [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/tags/releases/)).

Once you have the version of Django you want, just run the following command inside the django directory:

```
python setup.py install
```

This will install that version of Django in your virtualenv.

Answer (score 3):

+1 for already mentioned solutions.

I just wanna add another solution.

To install a [specific version](https://prnt.sc/jerlxe) of Django (say 1.10.x),

1. Clone the Django repo from [Github](https://github.com/django/django.git).

   `git clone https://github.com/django/django.git`
2. Go into the directory and checkout to the specific branch.

   `cd django`

   `git checkout origin/stable/1.10.x`
3. Run install command.

   `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 2):

`pip install "django>=2.2,<3"`
To install djnago 2.2

Comment: Excellent! I wanted latest version of django 3, so I used: pip3 install "django>=3.2,<4". Note: Double quotes are needed for this command to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install django==(the desired version ex: 1.8.4)
```

This will allow you to install the desired version, and I tried on OS:Windows10 and it perfectly worked.