# How do I get an older version of Django? Pip says could not find version

Tags: python, django

I need Django 0.96. I have a huge Django project which I need to run, but it's very very tied to 0.96, I could take a looot of time to port it 1.x

When I do `pip install django==0.96` I get this

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django==0.96 (from versions: 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.2, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.3, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5)
```

How do I Install Django 0.96?

Comment: Indeed, that old version is [not available from PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/).

Comment: @MartijnPieters So, any idea? :)

Comment: It is probably not supported anymore, you need to manually download the package and install it from source (just download, unpack and run `python setup.py install`). However, I strongly recommend taking the time and moving forward. There's a lot that have changed (for the better)

Comment: It is not [available on GitHub either](https://github.com/django/django/releases).

Comment: @yuvi Can't find the package to download either!

Comment: Why do you need *that* old a version at all?

Comment: make an install from source not from package, find the version download it and install it.

Comment: Have an old project that I have to re-run. It's fine, and was in production. Only thing is it is heavily tied to Django 096

Comment: Note that there never *was* a 0.9.6 release. Only 0.96.x releases. Are you 100% certain that you need 0.9.6?

Comment: See jabaldonedo's answer for the link. But really, you should update it. it's not just a matter of getting with the time, it's also a security issue

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Yeah no it's 0.96.x!

Comment: I would strongly recommend trying to update to the later version - preferably in a version agnostic manner - if all your usage follows the API then you should find it reasonably trivial to do the updates - _(especially if you have some test cases)_

Comment: Moving from 0.96/ 1.0 to the latest version is less than trivial for even a small codebase. There are plenty of breaking changes between now and then. You can sort of work around the move to staticfiles and handling the addition of CSRF form protection is easy enough, but it's almost always "interesting". I've done a number of these for a web host; my favorite was the one tied to a Postgres driver that's no longer available. That took some surgery. I'm happy to give advice to anyone who needs to do this. (Also: no one still running 0.96 ever has test cases :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can install from git repo:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/django/django@c939b2a1cb22b5035b1ccf90ee7686f334e6049d#egg=django==0.96.5
```

Comment: github repo is a big monster, give it few minutes and it will work :)

Comment: I have a similar problem but require 1.2.5 - tried looking on Github for a URL for 1.2.5 like the above, but no joy. Any hints?

Comment: @DaveEveritt pip install git+https://github.com/django/django@1.2.5#egg=django==1.2.5

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli - looks like that syntax would work for any Django version - true?

Comment: @DaveEveritt if you find the git ref yes :) (btw I would not recommend using this approach to install versions that are available on pypi!)

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli finding the git ref was the problem (how did you do it?), so thanks for the example. No, I won't use this method  with versions from pipy, although 1.2.7 is there :-)

Comment: @DaveEveritt most of django releases are tagged (https://github.com/django/django/releases)

Comment: Any ideas here how to make pip freeze work with this? After this is done it says that I need Django==0.96.5, but I can't distribute this as a `requirements.txt` file?

Answer (score 9):

That old version is not available on pip. Here are the links to versions of branch 0.96.x: [0.96.5](https://www.djangoproject.com/m/releases/0.96/Django-0.96.5.tar.gz), [0.96.4](https://www.djangoproject.com/m/releases/0.96/Django-0.96.4.tar.gz), [0.96.3](https://www.djangoproject.com/m/releases/0.96/Django-0.96.3.tar.gz), [0.96.2](https://www.djangoproject.com/m/releases/0.96/Django-0.96.2.tar.gz), [0.96.1](https://www.djangoproject.com/m/releases/0.96/Django-0.96.1.tar.gz) and [0.96](https://www.djangoproject.com/m/releases/0.96/Django-0.96.tar.gz)

Comment: Thank you very much. I badly wanted to accept your answer too, but then the `pip install` from `git` was a lazier answer which I liked better than having to untar and `python setup.py install`, not a big deal though, but really really thanks! :)