# Install scrapy on CentOS with multiple python versions

Tags: python, scrapy, pip

I have a default Python install on the server (version 2.6.6) and installed a 2.7.5 to be able to install Scrapy.  However, during installation, it seems that Scrapy took the 2.6.6 binaries and libraries.  After installation, of course, Scrapy won't run (Scrapy 0.20.0 requires Python 2.7).

How do I install Scrapy using the 2.7.5 binaries and libraries.  I've tried doing a symlink of  the python binary to point to python2.7 to no avail. Is there a way to define this on pip? For now assume that we can't remove the 2.6.6 copy on the server.

Thank you.

Comment: can't u specify which to install? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220280/how-do-i-install-an-old-version-of-django-on-virtualenv)

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is pip is still installing packages to your Python 2.6.6 installation, try reinstalling pip for your Python 2.7.5 installation.

If `which python` points to your new installation try the instructions here:
http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#install-or-upgrade-pip

Comment: It's the first one. How do you install pip for the 2.7.5 install? I got pip by doing 'yum install python-pip' as 'python2.7 get-pip.py' is not working for me.

Comment: Ok, was able to install pip-2.7, but anything I install using pip-2.7 doesn't work:
usr/local/bin/pip-2.7 install Scrapy

Downloading/unpacking Scrapy
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/

/usr/local/bin/pip-2.7 install simplejson
Downloading/unpacking simplejson
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/

Comment: I just ended up installing the dependencies, one by one, by hand (downloading from pypi.python.org/simple/<dependencyhere>, untar them, then python2.7 setup.py install).