# Not able to run django-admin script on ubuntu

Tags: python, django, django-admin

When I ran the following command :

```
django-admin startproject project_name
```

I got the following error :

```
The program 'django-admin' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install python-django-common
```

I did what it told me to and nwo I get the following error:

```
Cannot find installed version of python-django or python3-django.
```

on running the same command, I am not able to understand if I had installed django , then why was django-admin script not installed

Note that django is installed which is verified by the following:

```
$ python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
1.7
```

Answer (score 1):

try this command, `django-admin.py startproject example`, if it doesnt work try creating a virtual environment and installing django again

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install django with [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) as stated in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220280/how-do-i-install-an-old-version-of-django-on-virtualenv), also maybe the best option is to use a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/), you may find it in the ubuntu repository via synaptic.